# Using spark to merge data in sorted order to csv files

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-csv

I have a data set like this:

```
name  time val
---- ----- ---
fred 04:00 111
greg 03:00 123
fred 01:00 411
fred 05:00 921
fred 11:00 157
greg 12:00 333
```

And csv files in some folder, one for each unique name from the data set:

```
fred.csv
greg.csv
```

The contents of fred.csv, for example, looks like this:

```
00:00 222
10:00 133
```

My goal is to efficiently merge the dataset to the CSV's in sorted time order so that fred.csv, for example, ends up like this:

```
00:00 222
01:00 411
04:00 111
05:00 921
10:00 133
```

In reality, there are thousands of unique names, not just two. I use union and sort functions to add rows in order, but I have not been successful with partitionBy,  for each, or coalesce in getting the rows to their proper CSV files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Import and declare necessary variables**

```
val spark = SparkSession.builder
  .master("local")
  .appName("Partition Sort Demo")
  .getOrCreate;

import spark.implicits._
```

**Create dataframe from source file**

```
val df = spark.read
  .format("csv")
  .option("header", "true")
  .option("inferSchema", "true")
  .csv("csv/file/location")

//df.show()
+----+-----+---+
|name| time|val|
+----+-----+---+
|fred|04:00|111|
|greg|03:00|123|
|fred|01:00|411|
|fred|05:00|921|
|fred|11:00|157|
|greg|12:00|333|
+----+-----+---+
```

> ### Now `repartition` dataframe by name and `sort` each partition then `save` them
>
> ```
> //repartition
> val repartitionedDf = df.repartition($"name")
>
> for {
>   //fetch the distinct names in dataframe use as filename
>   distinctName <- df.dropDuplicates("name").collect.map(_ (0))
> } yield {
>   import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.lit
>
>   repartitionedDf.select("time", "val")
>     .filter($"name" === lit(distinctName)) //filter df by name
>     .coalesce(1)
>     .sortWithinPartitions($"time") //sort
>     .write.mode("overwrite").csv("location/" + distinctName + ".csv") //save
> }
> ```

### Note:

The content of CSV file is available in highlighted files.

[image: Output files location]

Comment: @GregClinton: regarding 4th comment, in Spark, we can't save the output as files, alternativity we rename/merge files inside the folder by running another job on output files. Here we rename part-** files to same as the folder name but in another location.

Comment: @GregClinton: regarding 1st comment, if we want complete all in one go we can save as one filename(of course it's also folder) by running `save` on  `repartitionedDf`